# Selecting from multiple lists in iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm new to iOS developing and want to know how to make a menu (btn1,btn2,...) on which when you click on it to be taken to a list of documents (example1,example2,...) and when you on them to display a preview of the document, and the option to view it in iBooks or Pages.

Like the image below.

Thank you :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEli4.png

Answer (score 0):

You can make a UITableView to display various options. On selection of an option you can show them a UISplitViewController with left being a list and right side being a preview. Note that you cannot push a UISplitViewController but just add it as subview.